# Cannot connect HTTPS target via HttpSocket using an HTTP proxy

Tags: https, proxy, cakephp-2.0, http-proxy

When connecting an external https url, the http proxy server would return the following error:

> stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
>   Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>   stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>   stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080
>   (Unknown error)

It seems cakephp HttpSocket uses the url's scheme to connect the proxy. Can we separate the scheme between proxy and the real destination?

more from the code:

```
    $http_socket = new HttpSocket();
    $http_socket->configProxy(array(
        'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
        'port' => '8080'
    ));

    $results = $http_socket->post(
        'https://yyy.yyy.yyy'
    );
```